# Which proforms have "Tom" as antecedent in "When Tom won, his friends cheered for him"

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> When Tom won the talent contest, his friends cheered for him.

In this sentence, what is the pronoun that matches the antecedent *Tom*?  I suspect it is "him", but can it also be "his" in this case?

Comment: *Him* refers to Tom.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence could be expanded into:

> When Tom won the talent contest, Tom's friends cheered for Tom.

Thus both "his" and "him" ultimately refer to "Tom".

Answer (score 0):

The referent of *his* is the implied *Tom's*.